Understanding the Role of $S \to SS$ in the Grammar for `if-else` Constructs
In the book by Hopcroft, Ullman, and Motwani, a grammar is presented to describe the if-else construct in a C program, under the constraint that every else must be paired with a preceding if. The grammar is:
$$S \to \epsilon \mid SS \mid iS \mid iSeS,$$
where $i$ represents an if and $e$ represents an else.
I am struggling to understand the necessity of the production $S \to SS$. If we remove this production, what valid strings would no longer be generable? Could someone clarify its role and provide examples of strings that depend on this rule?

This is a grammar for generating "sequences of if-else statements". The grammar as given is intentionally ambiguous and with a redundant SS production rule for the sake of the exercise. But in a typical programming language with an unambiguous syntax, for example S -> ϵ | SS | i(S) | i(S)e(S) (ignoring the ambiguity about associating sequences of three or more S) the purpose of a production rule such as S -> SS is that each if or else block may contain sequences of if-else statements (as well as other constructs), so you can write i(i(S)i(S)). It is also possible and commonplace to have separate symbols for "statements" and "sequences of statements".
